# getElementByID + .appendhild() [TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom component called 'Article', and I'm trying to show all articles, by fetching them from a database and rendering them as an 'Article' component.

```js
function renderArticle(doc){
    var article = '<Article name="' + doc.data().name + '" content="' + doc.data().content + '" id="' + doc.data().id + '"/>'
    document.getElementById('articles-list').appendChild(article)

}
 
const db = firebase.firestore()
db.collection('articles').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      renderArticle(doc)
    })
  })
```

When I run it, the console returns `TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

I'm stuck...

Comment: because you are trying to append a string, a string is not a node

Comment: if you want to use `appendChild` you need to create a node element, with `var article = document.createElement("article")` for example. Or, if you want to go with the html string, which I suggest not to do, then use: `.innerHTML = article`

Comment: @CalvinNunes I create document.createElement("article") but I have to put 2 props in this components, how can I  do that ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I'd suggest just using `element.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", "text")` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: @G.Alp you should read some [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) about the language you are programming... start from this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @Calvin Nunes said you need to pass a Node to document.createElement(), but as you tagged reactjs maybe you could use some advice about it too.

In React the way we have to render data that comes asynchronously (e.g. the docs that you are getting from your DB) is to track them into the component state.

In a first moment we render null or some loading indicator and fire the request to get our data. When the data is loaded we set our state and due to that our component will rerender an we can render what is in the state.

If you are using a component with lifecycles your code would be like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class ArticleList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      docs: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    db.collection('articles').get().then((snapshot) => {
      this.setState({docs: snapshot.docs});
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (docs === null) return null;
    return (
      <div>
        {docs.map((doc) => {
          return (
            <Article
              content={doc.data().content}
              key={doc.data().id}
              id={doc.data().id}
              name={doc.data().name}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ArticleList;
```

If you are using a function with hooks your code would be like:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Article from './Article'; // your other component

function ArticleList () {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState(null);
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('articles').get().then((snapshot) => {
      setDocs(snapshot.docs);
    })
  }, [db, setDocs]);
  if (docs === null) return null;
  return (
    <div>
      {docs.map((doc) => {
        return (
          <Article
            content={doc.data().content}
            key={doc.data().id}
            id={doc.data().id}
            name={doc.data().name}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ArticleList;
```

You will probably need to memoize the db object too in order to run the useEffect hooks just once, but this is not the point here.

Comment: If you want me to show the lifecycles way instead of the hooks way please let me know.

Comment: I think that lifecycles is easier for me... In my tutorial he already explain it :3

Comment: And just with curiosity, what does it mean : index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `ArticleList`. See '[url]' for more information.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. When rendering a list of components we need to provide each one a unique key prop. React uses this key internally to know when to update the DOM I guess. I will fix the code

Comment: So probably your doc.data().id isn't unique. Check that. In the last case you can use the array index number as key but this is not recommended and you should study the reason before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Element.insertAdjecentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert a string as HTML. The first parameter is the position where to add the HTML. The second parameter is the HTML to insert.

```
function renderArticle(doc){
    var article = '<Article name="' + doc.data().name + '" content="' + doc.data().content + '" id="' + doc.data().id + '"/>';
    document.getElementById('articles-list').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', article);
}
```

But since you are using React you should do it differently. From what I've found you should use the [`ReactDOM.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) function to render a component on the fly and insert it into the DOM.

```
function renderArticle(doc){
  var article = '<Article name="' + doc.data().name + '" content="' + doc.data().content + '" id="' + doc.data().id + '"/>';
  ReactDOM.render(article, document.getElementById('articles-list'));
}
```

Make sure to import the `ReactDOM` module to use it properly. Place the import at the top of your script.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

Comment: Thanks, the error disapear but it still show nothing

Comment: I've modified the answer to make it compliant with React. Try it again.

Comment: The console return : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier